# C++ how to rewrite a range based for loop to a normal one?

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a range based for loop like this:

```
for (auto& individual : population){
    individual.metadata.distance = distance(individual.tour);
}
```

Now I have to rewrite this into a normal for-loop in order to use OpenMP to parallelize my program, I have the following:

```
int length = population.size();
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    auto individual =* (population.begin() + i);
    individual.metadata.distance = distance(individual.tour);
}
```

However, the output becomes incorrect, so I am wondering if this is the way to rewrite a range based for-loop. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type is `population`?

Comment: Equivalent code is given in a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
auto individual =* (population.begin() + i);
```

This makes a copy, which appears to not be what you want.  I think you meant this:

```
auto& individual =* (population.begin() + i);
```

Answer (score 2):

If `population` provides a random-access iterator - and it probably does, given your use of `*(population.begin() + i)` - then you could rewrite your loop like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel
for (sometype::iterator individual = population.begin();
     individual < population.end();
     individual++)
{
    individual->metadata.distance = distance(individual->tour);
}
```

OpenMP supports parallel loops over random-access iterators since version 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need, If you are looking for each of the `population` parts then this will be equivalent:

```
for (Individual::iterator individual = population.begin(); individual != population.end(); individual++) {
```

This should be exactly the same as the `auto` for loop. If you need the count (as in `i`) you could approach it this way:

```
int counter = 0;
for (auto& individual : population){
    ...
    counter++;
```

This approach has the advantage of still using iterators, which are a good safe way to loop through your collections. But you can still check the count for whatever reason.

As to why your particular code is not working, use `auto& individual`.